# Give user permession with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an already deployed application on azure app service which uses azure AD for authentication and authorization.

Unfortunately the developer who worked on it is no longer available

- i got access to all Azure resources and source code but i cant figure out how can i add my azure account as one of the users to the app (i can login but its an empty view for me unlike what it used to be with the developer access).

Also i find the app registered on Azure AD and i am an owner there but still with no right access.

When i try to login localy from the frontend it say

```
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and 
cannot access the application '[some numbers] in that tenant. The 
 account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a 
 different account.
```

Would appreciate any help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: You say are able to login, so can you then debug through the code and check where it fails? If after auth, the redirect URL was correct then it will reach your app, then your app may be doing any Role based access check, debug or see through the code if any such check is made, your login may not be in that role group. Which language your app is written in?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I am no expert to .net programming, the app is deployed but when i try to login localy it say `Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '[some numbers] in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.` so i would like to add myself as user from active directory and stil cant figure out how

Comment: You can add you account as guest user to the Azure Active Directory in which the app registration is created. Then you would be able to login to your App

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT i confused because i am already a user in the Azure Active Directory

Comment: Are you able to login to the application with your Azure AD Account?

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT in the local angular front end i get that message in privious comment but when i try the url in the deployed azure web app resource i can get to the first view but cant see anything due to not having authorization it seem, any clue how can i fix that knowing ppl who worked on the project are no longer here?

Comment: Does the application have backend? If yes, where is it hosted?

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT yes there is many asp.net core microservices hosted in azure app service

Comment: Are these app services also authenticated using Azure AD?

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT i am not sure but i could accuess to the swagger of many of the services and test it and it worked

Comment: If the application you are accessing depends on any backend application for which Azure AD Authentication is enabled, you will not be able to authorise your application. You need to add the backend application permissions in your app registration

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT Thats the issue, my previous collegue had access but i dont, how can i authorise myself to the backend?

Comment: Check grant front end app access to back end in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux

Answer (score 0):

> I can login but it’s an empty view for me unlike what it used to be
> with the developer access

This is because your backend application is enabled with Azure AD Authentication.

After you sign in to your front-end application, you still can't access the data from the back-end app, because the back-end app now requires Azure Active Directory sign-in from the front-end app

To access the application, follow the below steps:

- Grant the front-end access to the back end
- Configure App Service to return a usable token
- Use the token in your code

You can refer **Enable authentication and authorization for front-end app** in [Authenticate users E2E - Azure App Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux) for the detailed steps